# Probabilty of A and D but not B and not C

Tags: probability

I am trying to work a probability question and I am stumped.

Imagine there are 4 signs on the side of the road and each sign has a "chance of being seen" equal to the following

sign A: .75
sign B: .82
sign C: .87
sign D: .9

What are the chances of A AND D being seen, but NOT B and NOT C.  (I saw the first and fourth signs, but I did not see the 2nd or the third).

Comment: Do you mean "but not $B$ and not $C$"? Or "but not $B$ or not $C$"?

Comment: Please, edit the title or the question. They state different questions.

Comment: The chance of [stuff ... and ($B$ being seen AND not $B$ being seen) and ...] is pretty easy to work out. Please clarify the wording.

Comment: I think I fixed so the questions are the same in the title and description, and are more descriptive.  Thanks

Comment: It's important to specify whether the events are independent, and if not, how they relate. For example, if two of the signs are on opposite sides of the road, then someone driving by is less likely to see one if they see the other.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Supposing independent events, you can compute $$0.75\times 0.9\times (1-0.82)\times (1-0.87)?$$

The idea is: you want $A \wedge D\wedge \neg B \wedge \neg C$.

Comment: It might help to explain how you arrived at that answer. Also, are you asking or answering? :-) Regards

Comment: This was the correct answer. ANd I believe it be explained that if you wanted to calculate the odds of all 4 events happening it would be .75 * .82 * .87 * .9.  In this case, we are swapping the odds for B and C with the odds of NOT seeing the sign, which is the result we are looking for...

In short, you are calculating using all of the percentage chances for the outcome you want to happen for each sign.

Comment: @Aaron You really should take the comment on the main question that was made by dfeuer to heart. The answer you have accepted is _not_ the correct answer in all cases. It _is_ the correct answer if the events $A,B,C,D$ are independent events, something that neither you nor Sigur appear to have thought worth mentioning.